# dynamic pdf need to open print box directly

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, fpdf

i personally would think it's not possible, but maybe somebody knows.
(PHP, PDF created with fpdf) I would like to know if it is possible to open that pdf and open the print box directly.

More or less the same as one could do window.print() with html/JS.

any one any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - how to open print window while a pdf file is opened in web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210423/php-how-to-open-print-window-while-a-pdf-file-is-opened-in-web-page)

Comment: sorry just see its a duplicate q...

Comment: I've read about solutions for this that require embedding some JavaScript in the PDF file using Acrobat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should embed some javascript code to do it.

You'll need this component too:
http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/36/

In the end of the page you have an example where you can show a print dialog after user open the document.

Answer (score 1):

There is code that uses JavaScript to print the page. Means the reader has to have JS enabled.

[Add Print Support](http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/36/)

Comment: Sir, I tried the method that you suggested and it works like a charm!! But is it possible to open the printer dialogue in the webpage itself on click of a button without going to the next tab where the pdf is displayed and on top of that the printer dialogue opens?