# Open and Print PDF using php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, printf

I want to write a function that takes a url as an argument and then it goes and prints the pdf... how can i do that?

should i open the file using php and then print it using javascript?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Well, I THINK the maximum you can do is something like this: [dynamic pdf need to open print box directly][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265815/dynamic-pdf-need-to-open-print-box-directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP header() function.

Try look here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I think he's asking for a PHP or javascript library that will actually open the file and convert it to HTML...

Comment: am not sure what to do with the header

Answer (score 0):

> and prints the pdf

PHP and javascript are usually used for generating web pages - there is no direct link to printing on either the server nor the client. Even in contexts where this would make sense, there is no printing API in either language so you'd need to use the facilities within the OS or another tool - and you've provided no details about this either.

Where is the PHP running? Where is the Javascript running? Where do you want the PDF printed (client/server)? What OS is running at the end where printing should happen?